Robocopy - Exclude directories with a specific name
I have the following script that runs on a schedule to back up a folder from my PC to my NAS:
robocopy "E:\Video Recording" "\\192.168.1.65\NAS-ARCHIVE\Video Recording" /mir /xx /z /w:5 /r:5 /mt:16

In my source directory of E:\Video Recording there can be folders called "Encoded" at various levels. I need to ignore the folders named "Encoded" as these are not source files I care about.
I want to update my script to basically be "Copy everything from this directory, but ignore all folders named Encoded"
Is it possible to do that?

Does that work for nested folders of the same name as well? For example, E:\Video Recording\2024\June\Encoded and E:\Video Recording\2024\July\Encoded and also E:\Video Recording\2024\Encoded ?

The option /XD(Exclude Directory) is the way to go. And yes, this will exclude the given directory name on any sublevel.
